# C# CmdLet binary | add $env:Variable directly on import

Tags: c#, powershell, binary

i am writing a c# binary cmdlet. at end it should installed on machine for immediate using when starting the ISE or PS-Console without Import-Module.

now i want to provide machine-wide some own $env:Variables like ex. $env:ProgramFiles. how i can do this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
for a more descriptive example here a code sniped:

```
namespace InstallTools.UpdateEnvironment
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsData.Update, "Environment")]
    [OutputType(typeof(UpdateEnvironment))]
    public class UpdateEnvironment : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Position                         = 1,
                    Mandatory                       = false,
                    ValueFromPipeline               = true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
                    ParameterSetName                = "ENVIRONMENT")]
        public SwitchParameter SetEnvironment { get; set; }


        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            if(SetEnvironment .IsPresent)
            {
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CDir", this.MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot);
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CurrentTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if i call in PS Update-Environment -SetEnvironment all the doings will executed. in my case, Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ("test", "testval") causes an $env:test to be available at runtime.

However, I want the variables to be initialized automatically when the ISE is opened, without calling Update-Environment.

Thanks at all!!

Comment: For the first question ('use modules without `Import-Module`), you should store your module file(s) in one of the standard module locations or update the `PsModulePath` environment variable to include the new location, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-7#how-to-install-a-module).  Can you clarify the second part about environment variables, as it's not clear what you're asking?

Comment: please format your code and add some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For immediate usage of your module when starting the ISE or PS-Console typing Import-Module you can modify the PSModulePath environment variable.

According to [Modifying the PSModulePath Installation Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path?view=powershell-7).

The PSModulePath environment variable stores the paths to the locations of the modules that are installed on disk. PowerShell uses this variable to locate modules when the user does not specify the full path to a module. The paths in this variable are searched in the order in which they appear.

When PowerShell starts, `PSModulePath` is created as a system environment variable with the following default value: `$HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Modules`; `$PSHOME\Modules on Windows and $HOME/.local/share/powershell/Modules`: `usr/local/share/powershell/Modules` on Linux or Mac, and `$HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`; `$PSHOME\Modules` for Windows PowerShell.

**This article also answered the second part of your question :**

To add paths to the `PSModulePath` environement variable, use one of the 3 following methods:

1) *To add a temporary value that is available only for the current session*, run the following command at the command line:

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + "$([System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator)$MyModulePath"
```

2) *To add a persistent value that is available whenever a session is opened*, add the above command to a PowerShell profile file ($PROFILE)>

```
$profile.AllUsersAllHosts
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
```

For more information about profiles, see [about_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7).

3) *To add a persistent variable to the registry*, create a new user environment variable called PSModulePath using the Environment Variables Editor in the System Properties dialog box.

*To add a persistent variable by using a script*, use the .Net method `SetEnvironmentVariable` on the `System.Environment` class. For example, the following script adds the C:\Program Files\Fabrikam\Module path to the value of the PSModulePath environment variable for the computer. To add the path to the user PSModulePath environment variable, set the target to "User".

```
$CurrentValue = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $CurrentValue + [System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator + "C:\Program Files\Fabrikam\Modules", "Machine")
```

Comment: Thank you @JPBlanc for the detailed answer. that gives some clarity :-)

More detailes for my other question see EDIT above.